# Using Java JNA and native library on Raspberry Pi

Tags: java

I am trying to use JNA on raspbian. I have installed libjna-java

```
sudo apt-get install libjna-java
```

When I run my java application I get an "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError"
for libjnidispatch.so. This library file is supposed to get installed into /usr/lib/jni/ but libjnidispatch.so is not in my file system. I have been trying to get my hands on this library file but can't find it anywhere on the net. Anybody have a suggestion on how to locate and download this file?

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=64803

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=64803 Not really a good solution right now as openjdk10 is expecting JNA Native library 5.2.0 and is getting 4.0.1 in the latest libjna-jni 4.2.2